# SQLite - Sum a union query with 3 databases

Tags: sqlite

I have the following query in SQLite.

```
ATTACH 'database1.s3db' AS DB1;
ATTACH 'database2.s3db' AS DB2;
ATTACH 'database3.s3db' AS DB3;

SELECT count(DB1.tblPool.AnswerR2) 
  FROM DB1.tblPool
 WHERE qid = '96fb11e1-87b0-4cae-983b-9b9d849acbab' AND 
       CorrectAns = 'A2' AND 
       DB1.tblPool.AnswerR2 != 'NA'
UNION ALL
SELECT count(DB2.tblPool.AnswerR2) 
  FROM DB2.tblPool
 WHERE qid = '96fb11e1-87b0-4cae-983b-9b9d849acbab' AND 
       CorrectAns = 'A2' AND 
       DB2.tblPool.AnswerR2 != 'NA'
UNION ALL
SELECT count(DB3.tblPool.AnswerR2) 
  FROM DB3.tblPool
 WHERE qid = '96fb11e1-87b0-4cae-983b-9b9d849acbab' AND 
       CorrectAns = 'A2' AND 
       DB3.tblPool.AnswerR2 != 'NA';
```

And the results I get are something like below:

```
Table result
|1          |
|0          |
|0          |
```

What are the suggested best methods to get the sum?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Common Table Expression](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```sql
WITH counts(c) AS (
SELECT ... -- your original query here
)
SELECT sum(c) FROM counts;
```